# Understanding '$this->model'

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am a cakePHP newbie, who has just been assigned to work on an existing system built with cakePHP 1.3. As I get familiar with the project and it's contents their are snippets of code I don't quite understand. Again and again (usually in a controller file) I see these:

'$this->model'

'$this->Model'

'$this->{$this->model}'

Searching google, the cake docs, and stackoverflow has yet to reveal a concise explanation of what exactly these strings are referring to. Many of the controllers I am working with have more than one model with which they interact, how do I know which one these snippets are invoking?

For instance web_forms_controller.php has 3 models which go with it web_forms.php, web_forms_field.php, and web_forms_submission.php. I feel like I am missing something basic here, but RTM has yet to reveal the answer I am after.

So in the above instance I am guessing that '$this->model' and '$this->Model' seen in web_forms_controller.php refer to the web_forms.php model. What '$this->{$this->model}' is a reference to in this case I have no idea.

Comment: Those are almost certainly not part of the CakePHP framework, but rather part of the codebase you're working in.  I suspect it's a string that holds one of your models' aliases.  $this->{$this->model} would then be getting the model that has that alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off CakePHP uses the "convention over configuration" convention. This heavily explains a lot! :)
There is a thingy called [Inflector](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-Inflector.html) - it "just" 'pluralizes and singularizes English nouns. Used by Cake's naming conventions throughout the framework.'

This combined with the conventions and a few key principles makes it possible that Cake tells which Class to bind to which other.

So, `$this->model` in a controller will be the Model directly associated with this Controller.
For example in a `UsersController`, `$this->model` would be the `User` model.

Other binded models are defined in the `$uses` property of the Controller.
Through `$this->model` you call only the controller's own model.
To call another binded model (for ex `Post`) use:

```
$this->Post->findAll();
```

`$this->model` i just a convenient shortcut from any given controller.